# Is it possible to have a space in the title of a column in a temporary table?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create the names of columns in a temporary table with spaces. The reason I need these spaces in the name is so that it connects properly with our asp.net application that will be using this as a data set. Because the columns from other regular tables have a space, the code is looking for an item in the data set with a space as well. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
declare @temp table (id int, scheduled start datetime)
```

but this is not allowed, and will throw an error. In the server side of my application (asp.net - vb) - the call to use this field looks like this

```
lblStart.text = DS.Item("Scheduled Start")
```

This is why I need the space in the name, in the temporary table, so that when using the regular results or results from the temporary table, the dataset will work for the same server side code. Is this possible? I have tried to use quotes, but not having any luck. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just wrap the name `scheduled start` in brackets like this:

```
declare @temp table (id int, [scheduled start] datetime)
```

Comment: Or double quotes (which is more standard)